# nhibernate two different databases in the same session

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

When writing sql, I can do

```
 BEGIN Trans t;
 SELECT a.name, b.name from db1.dbo.A as a
    JOIN db2.dbo.B as b
    ON b.aId = a.Id
 COMMIT Trans t;
```

When two databases are on the same database instance.

I am wondering how I can achieve this with database mapping. So that I don't need to create multiple sessions for queries involves different databases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating objects with NHibernate across multiple databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595866/populating-objects-with-nhibernate-across-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, so far I have not seen any other solution then creating a view within one database which does the cross DB query and then use nh mappings on that view, or maybe fully-qualified names. (see [duplicate-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595866/populating-objects-with-nhibernate-across-multiple-databases) below your post).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually like the "fully qualified name" approach better. Will try it and let you know the result.

Comment: Fully qualified names work for namespaces and dB's. . Never tried with 2dbs.

Comment: Fully qualified name worked. I have tested with two different databases running on the same database instance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility to do it with DB synonyms. It is not an optimal solution performance-wise, but it might solve your current bind.
[SQL Server Synonyms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx)

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, and I don't see why this would cause performance issue. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It does not solve the DB linking problem. It really depends on your needs and configuration, if the cross databases queries are sparse and light, you might not feel it. But on heavy load, frequent or with scalability potential cases, you should consider to invest to time to readjust your database schemes.